# Any pointers on setting up Chef push jobs?

Tags: chef-infra

I followed the [Chef push jobs](https://docs.chef.io/install_push_jobs.html) page, but am still confused. For example, that page describes this

```
Add the following default attributes on all nodes that are managed by Chef push jobs:

"push_jobs": {
  "package_url": "<package_url>",
  "package_checksum": "<checksum>"
}
```

But what is package_url and checksum? Where do I get those?

In general, is there a simple tutorial on how to set up Chef push jobs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the URL and checksum on the [Chef Push download page](http://downloads.chef.io/push-jobs-client/). After you've selected your platform, you can right click the download link and copy the source code. The page will also let you copy the checksum from below the download link.

Comment: You're correct thank you. The instructions are just not clear on what those two attributes should have.

Answer (score 2):

I just want to supplement the answers already given, thanks to Michael Lapidakis and kirill_I as their answers helped me to figure out how to bootstrap a **windows server node** to have chef client software and the push-jobs client installed using **winrm**.

Rather than update the push-jobs recipe's attributes file I passed the **package_url** and **package_checksum** as json attributes on the command line of the knife command. kirill_I is correct in that the hash given on the download page is SHA1 and not SHA256 so it cannot be used as the checksum. The easiest way to get a checksum on a windows box is the use the powershell command **Get-FileHash** because sha256sum.exe is not available without an internet download. You have to toLower() the output because by default powershell gives it in upper case and chef sees that as two different checksums:

**COMPUTERNAME.DOMAIN [2015-10-27T09:25:59-07:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChecksumMismatch: windows_package[Opscode Push Jobs Client Installer for Windows v1.1.5] (push-jobs::windows line 29) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::ChecksumMismatch: remote_file[c:/chef/cache/opscode-push-jobs-client-windows-1.1.5-1.windows.msi] (dynamically defined) had an error: Chef: :Exceptions::ChecksumMismatch: Checksum on resource (411520) does not match checksum on content (411520)**

To get the hash in powershell use the following command, replacing the filename and directory with the version you downloaded from chef:

```
(Get-FileHash c:\Software\opscode-push-jobs-client-windows-1.1.5-1.windows.msi -Algorithm SHA256).Hash.toLower()
```

I then plugged that hash into the following knife bootstrap command:

```
knife bootstrap windows winrm COMPUTERNAME.DOMAIN --winrm-user Administrator --winrm-password 'password' --node-name COMPUTERNAME.DOMAIN --run-list 'recipe[push-jobs]' -j '{ \"push_jobs\": { \"package_url\": \"https://opscode-private-chef.s3.amazonaws.com/windows/2008r2/x86_64/opscode-push-jobs-client-windows-1.1.5-1.windows.msi\", \"package_checksum\": \"411520e6a2e3038cd018ffacee0e76e37e7badd1aa84de03f5469c19e8d6c576\" } }'
```

The json has to be escaped, otherwise I was getting a JSON parser error.

Comment: Have you had any luck adding a custom push-job command to the whitelist? When I do a search with knife it shows the custom job in the whitelist for the Windows node, however when I try to run it, the job immediately fails and on the Windows side it says the command is NOT in the whitelist

Comment: I haven't tried to do that myself. I have instead been relying on setting the run_list for the node [knife node run_list set COMPUTER.DOMAIN 'recipe[...]...'] and then running knife job start --timeout 600 'chef-client' COMPUTER.DOMAIN. We are just in the process of redoing our entire continuous delivery pipeline so I am in no way saying that is the way to go, just the way we have done it so far.

Comment: Replied to your original question about whitelisting after performing my own experiments on getting whitelisting to work, you are correct that it does appear to be a bug on the windows side. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33528588/add-custom-chef-push-job-to-windows-whitelist/33811130#33811130

Answer (score 1):

Agree with the main reply but the only problem with [Chef Push download page](http://downloads.chef.io/push-jobs-client/) is that it provides SHA1 signature that doesn't work by default. I had to calculate SHA256 using sha256sum.exe after I downloaded the package to make it work.