# Add custom Chef push job to Windows whitelist

Tags: windows, chef-infra

I am trying to add a push job to the Windows whitelist for the pushy-client. When I do a search with knife it shows the custom job in the whitelist for the Windows node. When I try to run it, the job immediately fails and on the Windows side it says the command is NOT in the whitelist.

I found this issue in GitHub: [Windows push service can't load whitelist](https://github.com/chef/chef-push/issues/3)

I was wondering if anyone has a workaround, suggestion on how to fix it, or knows where in the code this lives that I could monkey-patch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just confirming I get the same issue after fully testing your scenario, I added a test command to the white list of the push-jobs cookbook itself in the **attributes/default.rb** file:

```
default['push_jobs']['whitelist'] = { 'chef-client' => 'chef-client', 'new-command' => 'chef-client' }
```

and verified that the white list contains those commands when it was written to **C:\chef\push-jobs.client.rb** on the node I am attempting to run the command on after bootstrapping it with the push-jobs cookbook:

However, when I attempt to execute that command:

```
knife job start --timeout 600 'new-command' server.fqdn
```

I get immediate failure as well:

```
Started.  Job ID: db3a99728dbded7abd35ed40d4ec3d5f
Quorum_failed.
command:     new-command
created_at:  Thu, 19 Nov 2015 23:31:57 GMT
id:          db3a99728dbded7abd35ed40d4ec3d5f
nodes:
    nacked: server.fqdn
run_timeout: 600
status:      quorum_failed
updated_at:  Thu, 19 Nov 2015 23:31:57 GMT
```

I even restarted the **Pushy Client Service** windows service just to verify it didn't reload that config on service restart.

The only way I have been able to get the windows server to run the jobs I want it to run has been to modify the runlist before each run of the standard **chef-client** "command":

```
knife node run_list set server.fqdn 'recipe[cookbook::recipe1]'

knife job start --timeout 600 'chef-client' node.fqdn

knife node run_list set server.fqdn 'recipe[cookbook::recipe2]'

knife job start --timeout 600 'chef-client' node.fqdn
```

The bug seems to be in the Pushy Client Service windows service itself and there doesn't seem to be any movement on the bug you submitted.

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad to know it isn't just me.

Comment: You ever get movement on a solution please comment here, because I would really like a solution myself... : )

Comment: Has anyone tried this again recently? I repeated the steps outlined in the bug and this seems to now be working - I can add new commands to the whitelist using the push-jobs cookbook and the node attributes. This suggests that the above issue should now be answered?

Comment: Sorry, haven't gotten back to this area of the server configuration. I hope to get back to it "soon" and update my recipes so I can try it again.