# Add jobs to push job whitelist in chef

Tags: chef-infra, push, jobs, whitelist

I want to add commands to push jobs whitelist into multiple nodes without editing one by one, there is a way to do this?

I've allready tried this:

```
knife exec -E 'nodes.transform("name:A_NODE_NAME") do |n|
    n.set["push_jobs"]["whitelist"]["ntpdate"] = "ntpdate -u time"
  end'
```

as it's said [here](https://docs.chef.io/push_jobs.html) but it's not working:

The command runs well,

```
knife exec -E 'nodes.transform("name:zookeeper03") do |n|
    n.set["push_jobs"]["whitelist"]["dns"] = "chef-client -r system-configs::dns"
  end'
```

then i use `knife node edit zookeeper03` and the editor shows me

```
{
  "name": "zookeeper03",
  "chef_environment": "_default",
  "normal": {
    "tags": [

    ],
    "push_jobs": {
      "whitelist": {
        "dns": "chef-client -r system-configs::dns"
      }
    }
  }
```

but when tail the logs in that node after running knife job start "dns" zookeeper03, the log shows:

```
ERROR: [zookeeper03] Received commit c1fa30942d664c6df7213c71d79a74f3, but command 'dns' is not in the whitelist!
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Is the node attribute getting set?

Comment: I've updated the original question

Comment: Your `nodes.transform` syntax looks fine. One gotcha with editing node attributes is that if there is a daemon-mode run active on that machine when you do the edit, it can get stomped on due to API race conditions. Try stopping the chef service on that node first?

Comment: I rebooted the node, nothing changes, the error message is the same.

Comment: Please restart the push job service on client

Answer (score 0):

There is some bug with push job being whitelisted. I performed every steps like adding whitelist in cookbook and updating node attributes mentioned on https://docs.chef.io/install_push_jobs.html. Still No Luck. Only command it runs currently is chef-client from push jobs. Otherwise you can use following steps to perform tasks mentioned at this stack link [Add custom Chef push job to Windows whitelist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33528588/add-custom-chef-push-job-to-windows-whitelist?rq=1)